# Metamask: is this the correct account? it is different from the currently selected account in your wallet

Tags: metamask

When I run transaction on metamask,it does always connected to one address and it does not detect address change:

> is this the correct account? it is different from the currently
> selected account in your wallet

This happens only on Chrome Browser.

[image]

I am currently connceted to this account

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a dapp proposes a transaction (e.g. via `sendTransaction`) it is possible to specify the `from`. If the dapp specifies the from as the originally connected wallet then it will ignore the currently selected account.

Also not all accounts are automatically connected to the dapp with the latest MetaMask versions. If you switch your account make sure to connect also the newly selected account. This is indicated next to the account address

[image]